# TortoiseSVN Error while downloading Open Dental files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was trying to download open dental 13.1 version developer code via Tortoise SVN Checkout option, but ended up with following error every time.

`Failed to run the WC DB work queue associated with
 'F:\OpenDentalwc\Macros\ConversionMacro', work item 62 (file-install
 Macros/ConversionMacro/ConversionMacro.vsmacros 1 0 1 1)
Can't open file
 'F:\OpenDentalwc\.svn\pristine\71\71535ffbcdaaa8fc84a5e75f7449efcde47ce8e1.svn-base':
 Access is denied.`

Need some help to download the Open Dental code via Tortoise SVN.